# How do I install packages when using Ubuntu 18.04 LiveUSB?

Tags: apt, live-usb, data-recovery

I'm trying to use an Ubuntu 18.04 LiveUSB to recover a lost file.  I've booted into the LiveUSB.  Now, I need to install the 'testdisk' package.

I can run `$ sudo apt update` and `$ sudo apt upgrade` with normal output and no errors.  However, I can't install packages.  If I use `apt-cache show` to find a package, I always get a "No packages found" error.  For instance:

```
$ apt-cache show testdisk
N: Unable to locate package testdisk
E: No packages found
$ apt-cache show cowsay
N: Unable to locate package cowsay
E: No packages found
```

If I try to install, I always get results like

```
$ sudo apt install testdisk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package testdisk.
```

I am connected to the network and can browse the Internet normally from the LiveUSB.

This [AskUbuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1033874/572928) says that I ought to be able to install packages to the LiveUSB.  I don't need it to be persistent, I just need `testdisk` long enough to recover a file.

How can I install packages in an Ubuntu 18.04 LiveUSB?

Comment: Run `sudo apt update` again. Read the output. If you don't understand the output, then paste the output into your question.

Answer (score 2):

### Adding testdisk to a Live USB

**Testdisk is located in the Universe Repository.**

To enable, in terminal run: `sudo add-apt-repository universe`

Then run: `sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt install testdisk`

That should do it.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Bruni

Answer (score 0):

as you can use browser - you can download this as apt/deb from unofficial source and install from filemanager/terminal, you don't even have to use network because file installations are offline and as you downloaded it - save to another pendrive cause it can help you in future ;)

Comment: and here you have link to OFFICIAL source : https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download , it's even more official than in apt ;)